# Warning received when clicking links in Facebook application

Tags: facebook, chrome-for-android, hyperlinks

When I click some shared links in the Facebook app and Chrome opens, I get:

> Please be careful
>   for safety and privacy of your Facebook account, remember...

[image: screenshot here]

and when I try to click on Continue, I get:

> The page you requested cannot be found

[image: screenshot].

So how can I disable this annoying thing so the links open directly? It did before I started using Chrome and was using the default Android browser and each time I clicked a link there was no warning.

Comment: I don't have an answer to disable it - however **it is** part of Facebook's website; so I'm not sure you **can** disable it. You can see in the url the `php?u=http` part. Facebook is passed your URL and is just warning you. When it fails it's just Facebook failing. I used to have to try 3-4 times, both in Chrome and the Android browser before it would work.

Comment: it's interesting that on the stock browser it opened the link without any warning... then I selected to always open in Chrome and I got this.. don't know how to go back to the stock browser and I don't even want to.. would like this to work in Chrome.. I get that the FB generates that link, but don't know why it worked before.. and how to fix it now. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: I just had to be signed into Facebook in Chrome.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as an answer. :)

Comment: yes, it doesn't let me.. tomorrow it will